# Generating separate rows for each month in a date range

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, cursor, reporting

Basically I have one row of data, for example:

```
ID -   Start_Date -  End_Date

------------------------------------

XXA   1/23/14        3/12/14
```

And I want to create one row for each month between the `Start_Date` and `End_Date`, for each `ID`, for example:

```
ID -  Month -     Year

--------------------------

XXA  January      2014

XXA  February     2014

XXA  March         2014
```

Which is the best and most efficient way of doing this? I was thinking of using a cursor, but once this table is created, I need to join other ones to this one. I am new to oracle, and I am not sure if you can join other tables after you run a cursor and create a temporary table. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: first create a simple calendar table and populate it. Then join it. Let me know if it is clear enough or need more help to accomplish that.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a simple row generation technique by using the `CONNECT BY` syntax:

```
with sample_data as 
  (select 'XXA' id, to_date('1/23/14','MM/DD/RR') start_date, to_date('3/12/14','MM/DD/RR') end_date from dual)
select id, to_char(add_months(start_date,level - 1),'Month YYYY') date_column
from sample_data
connect by level <= extract(month from end_date) - extract(month from start_date) + 1;
```

**Edit**
Adding `DISTINCT` should allow this to work across rows, I believe, although I would be interested to be proven wrong.
**Edit 2** Modified example to handle multiple years (should have done that originally). (See example http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/9eecb/4097/0.)

```
with sample_data as 
  ( select 'XXA' id, to_date('1/23/14','MM/DD/RR') start_date, to_date('3/12/15','MM/DD/RR') end_date from dual union all    
    select 'XXB' id, to_date('4/12/14','MM/DD/RR') start_date, to_date('6/18/15','MM/DD/RR') end_date from dual )
select distinct 
  id,
  to_char(add_months(start_date,level - 1),'Month YYYY') date_column,
  add_months(start_date,level -1) sortkey
from sample_data
connect by level <= ceil(months_between(trunc(end_date,'MM'), trunc(start_date,'MM'))) + 1
order by id, sortkey;
```

In my sandbox DB this yields:

```
ID  DATE_COLUMN     SORT_COL
XXA January   2014  23-JAN-2014 00:00:00
XXA February  2014  23-FEB-2014 00:00:00
XXA March     2014  23-MAR-2014 00:00:00
XXB April     2014  12-APR-2014 00:00:00
XXB May       2014  12-MAY-2014 00:00:00
XXB June      2014  12-JUN-2014 00:00:00
```

Comment: Hi Wolf, thanks for your help. Your example would work well if I have just one row, but I need a solution for a table with each row containing 1 ID and a date range.

Comment: ID -   Start_Date -  End_Date

Comment: XXA   1/23/14        3/12/14

Comment: XXB   4/12/14        6/18/14

Comment: @dorianpc See my edit. I _think_ this would still work for you by adding `DISTINCT` to the query.

Comment: Could this be adjusted so it works with data from multiple years?

Comment: @freekvd Yes, I should have done that originally. See the modified query above (with link to SQL Fiddle).

Answer (score 0):

To get the expected result some year-month data is needed. I'd suggest two possible ways to provide it:

1. create a table or view containing all possible year-months;
2. create a table function which returns required year-months only.

Others options assume implicit generation of year-month data what I think is not as good, as a obvious straight-forward solution.

The 2nd option (in theory) might be faster on bigger input data, however I wouldn't recommend it since you say nothing about performance and it's a little more complicated than the 1st one.

The simplest and easy-to-use solution is:

```
create table year (id int primary key);
    insert into year values (2014);
    insert into year values (2015);
    insert into year values (2016);


create table month (id int primary key, name char(255));
    insert into month values (1, 'Jan');
    insert into month values (2, 'Feb');
    insert into month values (3, 'Mar');
    insert into month values (4, 'Apr');
    insert into month values (5, 'May');
    insert into month values (6, 'Jun');
    insert into month values (7, 'Jul');
    insert into month values (8, 'Aug');
    insert into month values (9, 'Sep');
    insert into month values (10, 'Oct');
    insert into month values (11, 'Nov');
    insert into month values (12, 'Dec');


create table data (id char(15) primary key , start_date date, end_date date);
    insert into data 
      values ('XXA', to_date('1/23/14','MM/DD/RR'), to_date('3/12/14','MM/DD/RR'));
    insert into data
      values ('XXB', to_date('4/12/14','MM/DD/RR'), to_date('6/18/14','MM/DD/RR'));


create or replace view calendar as
    select y.id*100 + m.id as id, y.id as year, m.name as month 
      from year y, month m;


select d.id, c.month, c.year 
    from  calendar c, data d
    where c.id between to_char(d.start_date, 'yyyymm') 
               and to_char(d.end_date, 'yyyymm');
```

The output is:

```
XXA|Jan|2014
---+---+----
XXA|Feb|2014
---+---+----
XXA|Mar|2014
---+---+----
XXB|Apr|2014
---+---+----
XXB|May|2014
---+---+----
XXB|Jun|2014
```

It's important to populate Year table in advance, otherwise it works till 2016.